# Unable to create Aux folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, directory

In VS2012 seems that is not possible to create a project folder with the name "Aux".
If you try to add a folder in your project and name it "Aux" an error message appears, saying that folder name could not contains `;*?|"<>` O.o

Have you experencied the same situation? Is there a way to solve this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Windows limitation as Aux is a system name. Naming conventions can be found in the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx).

Other examples include:

CON, PRN, NUL, COM1, COM2, LPT1, LPT2, etc.

Comment: MS would have to write a clearer message. Anyway, thank you for your reply.